# $ 0 < a < b\,\Rightarrow\, b\bmod p\, <\, a\bmod p\ $ for some prime $p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

If  $\,a < b\,$ are  natural numbers then  a prime $\,p\,$ exists such that $\  a\bmod p\, >\, b\bmod p.$

The task seems understandable, but I have no idea how to prove this statement.

Comment: Very simple and nice question

Comment: Thanks, but proving is probably not that simple! :)

Comment: @BillDubuque:  I would think for all natural $a,b$ such that $a \lt b$, there is a prime $p$ such that $a \pmod p \gt b \pmod p$

Comment: @RossMillikan: I think that the question might be mis-phrased. Perhaps it should be something like "if there exists a number $a<n<b$ such that $a>b\pmod{n}$, then there must be a number $a<p<b$ such that $p$ is prime".

Comment: Feel free to edit this question, I know I am not good at saying tasks :D

Comment: I like the idea of a prime with an attitude.

Comment: What is p for a=4 and b=5?

Comment: p=5 works, a has 4 as remainder, but b as 0.

Comment: What order relation are you putting on $\Bbb{Z}/p \Bbb{Z}$? The usual order on $\Bbb{Z}$ doesn't induce one, because for any fixed $a<b$ there is an $a' > b$ with $a \equiv a' \pmod{p}$.

Answer (score 1):

If there is some prime that divides $b$ and not $a$, that prime $p$ will have $a \pmod p \gt 0, b \pmod p = 0$.

Assuming that all factors of $a$ also divide $b$:

If $a=2$ there is some odd prime $p$ that divides $b-1$ and $a \pmod p = 2 \gt b\pmod p = 1$

If $a=3$ there is some odd prime $p$ that divides either $b-2$ or $b-1$ and $a \pmod p = 3 \gt b\pmod p $

If $a = 4$, one of $b-1, b-3$ must have a prime factor $p$ greater than $3$ as they cannot both be powers of three.  We have $a \pmod p=4 \gt b \pmod p$

If $a \ge 5$, consider the interval $[b-a+1,b-1]$  It consists of $a-1$.  As there are less than $a-1$ primes less than $a$, one of these numbers will have a prime factor $p$ greater than $a$.  I haven't justified this, but the idea is that not enough of them can only have factors smaller than $a$.  We will have $a \pmod p = a \gt b\pmod p $

Comment: It's not true that the numbers in $[b-a+1,b-1]$ are coprime to $a$, or even that they are divisible by primes that don't divide $a$. For example when $a = 12, b = 24$, the number $18$ is in that interval.

Comment: @Arthur: Your point is well taken.  I just need one to have a prime factor greater than $a$, but need a better argument.